# Load CSV to a database when columns can be added/removed by the vendor

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis, etl

I've got some SSIS packages that take CSV files that come from the vendor and puts them into our local database.  The problem I'm having is that sometimes the vendor adds or removes columns and we don't have time to update our packages before our next run, which causes the SSIS packages to abend.  I want to somehow prevent this from happening.

I've tried reading in the CSV files line by line, stripping out new columns, and then using an insert statement to put the altered line into the table, but that takes far longer than our current process (the CSV files can have thousands or hundreds of thousands of records).

I've started looking into using ADO connections, but my local machine has neither the ACE nor JET providers and I think the server the package gets deployed to also lacks those providers (and I doubt I can get them installed on the deployment server).

I'm at a loss as to what I can do to be able to load tables and be able to ignore newly added or removed columns (although if a CSV file is lacking a column the table has, that's not a big deal) that's fast and reliable.  Any ideas?

Comment: How did you read the CSV line by line?  How did you perform the insert?  What components did you use?

Comment: I used a csvreader to read the file.  The insert was via a sqlcommand object.

Comment: When you say csvreader, do you mean flat file source or is this some customer component.  The sqlcommand object does a row-by-row insert.  If you change this to an oledb destination, that will make a big improvement

Comment: flat file source.  How can changing this to oledb be faster?

Comment: I'll provide a more complete response as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went with a different approach, which seems to be working (after I worked out some kinks).  What I did was take the CSV file rows and put them into a temporary datatable.  When that was done, I did a bulk copy from the datatable to my database.  In order to deal with missing or new columns, I determined what columns were common to both the CSV and the table and only processed those common columns (new columns were noted in the log file so they can be added later).  Here's my BulkCopy module:

```
    Private Sub BulkCopy(csvFile As String)
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim rowCount As Int32 = 0
    Dim colCount As Int32 = 0
    Dim writeThis As ArrayList = New ArrayList

    tempTable = New DataTable()
    Try
        '1) Set up the columns in the temporary data table, using commonColumns

        For i = 0 To commonColumns.Count - 1
            tempTable.Columns.Add(New DataColumn(commonColumns(i).ToString))
            tempTable.Columns(i).DataType = GetDataType(commonColumns(i).ToString)
        Next

        '2) Start adding data from the csv file to the temporary data table

        While Not csvReader.EndOfData
            currentRow = csvReader.ReadFields() 'Read the next row of the csv file
            rowCount += 1
            writeThis.Clear()

            For index = 0 To UBound(currentRow)
                If commonColumns.Contains(csvColumns(index)) Then
                    Dim location As Integer = tableColumns.IndexOf(csvColumns(index))
                    Dim columnType As String = tableColumnTypes(location).ToString

                    If currentRow(index).Length = 0 Then
                        writeThis.Add(DBNull.Value)
                    Else
                        writeThis.Add(currentRow(index))
                    End If
                    'End Select
                End If
            Next

            Dim row As DataRow = tempTable.NewRow()
            row.ItemArray = writeThis.ToArray
            tempTable.Rows.Add(row)
        End While
        csvReader.Close()

        '3) Bulk copy the temporary data table to the database table.

        Using copy As New SqlBulkCopy(dbConnection)
            '3.1) Set up the column mappings
            For i = 0 To commonColumns.Count - 1
                copy.ColumnMappings.Add(commonColumns(i).ToString, commonColumns(i).ToString)
            Next

            '3.2) Set the destination table name
            copy.DestinationTableName = tableName

            '3.3) Copy the temporary data table to the database table
            copy.WriteToServer(tempTable)

        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        message = "*****ERROR*****" + vbNewLine
        message += "BulkCopy: Encountered an exception of type " + ex.GetType.ToString()
        message += ": " + ex.Message + vbNewLine + "***************" + vbNewLine
        LogThis(message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

There may be something more elegant out there, but this so far seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Look into BiML, which build and executes your SSIS Package dynamically based on the meta-data at run time.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this comment:

> I've tried reading in the CSV files line by line, stripping out new
>   columns, and then using an insert statement to put the altered line
>   into the table, but that takes far longer than our current process
>   (the CSV files can have thousands or hundreds of thousands of
>   records).

And this:

> I used a csvreader to read the file. The insert was via a sqlcommand
>   object.

It would appear at first glance that the bottleneck is not in the flat file source, but in the destination.  An OLEDB Command executes in a row by row fashion, one statement per input row.  By changing this to an OLEDB destination, it will convert the process to a bulk insert operation.  To test this out, just use the flat file source and connect it to a derived column.  Run that and check the speed.  If it's faster, change to the oledb destination and try again.  It also helps to be inserting into a heap (no clustered or nonclustered indexes) and use tablock.

However, this does not solve your whole varied file problem.  I don't know what the flat file source does if you are short a column or more from how you originally configured it at design time.  It might fail, or it might import the rows in some jagged form where part of the next row is assigned to the last columns in the current row.  That could be a big mess.

However, I do know what happens, when a flat file source gets extra columns.  I put in this connect item for it which was sadly rejected: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/963631/ssis-parses-flat-files-incorrectly-when-the-source-file-contains-unexpected-extra-columns

What happens is that the extra columns are concatenated into the last column.  If you plan for it, you could make the last column large and then parse in SQL from the staging table.  Also, you could just jam the whole row into SQL and parse each column from there.  That's a bit clunky though because you'll have a lot of CHARINDEX() checking the position of values all of the place.

An easier option might be to parse it in .Net in a script task using some combo of split() to get all the values and check the count of values in the array to know how many columns you have.  This would also allow you to direct the rows to different buffers based on what you find.

And lastly, you could ask the vendor to commit to a format.  Either a fixed number of columns or use a format that handles variation like XML.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a C# solution (I haven't checked it, but I think it works) for a source script component.

It will read the header into an array using split.

And then for each data row use the same split function and use the header value to check the column and use rowval to set the output.

You will need to put all the output columns in to the output area.

All columns that are not present will have a null value on exit.

```
public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
    {


        using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"[filepath and name]"))
        {
            while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                string FullText = sr.ReadToEnd().ToString();
                string[] rows = FullText.Split('\n');

                //Get header values
                string[] header = rows[0].Split(',');


                for (int i = 1; i < rows.Length - 1; i++)
                {
                    string[] rowVals = rows[i].Split(',');
                    for (int j = 0; j < rowVals.Length - 1; j++)
                    {

                        Output0Buffer.AddRow();
                        //Deal with each known header name
                        switch (header[j])
                        {
                            case "Field 1 Name": //this is where you use known column names
                                Output0Buffer.FieldOneName = rowVals[j]; //Cast if not string
                                break;
                            case "Field 2 Name":
                                Output0Buffer.FieldTwoName = rowVals[j]; //Cast if not string
                                break;
                            //continue this pattern for all column names
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }


    }
```